# wcf data service security configuration

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm in the process of setting up a WCF Data Services web service and I'm trying to sort out the security configuration. Although there's quite a lot of documentation out there for configuring WCF security, a lot of it seems to be outmoded or does not apply to my scenario.

Ultimately, I am planning on managing authorization of operations via [change interceptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744837(VS.100).aspx). Thus, all I really need is the simplest way to permit a client to pass credentials along with a request and to be able to authenticate those credentials against either AD or an ASP.NET membership provider (I'd much prefer the latter unless it makes things much more complicated).

I'm intending to manage encryption at the transport level (i.e. HTTPS).

I'm hoping that the eventual solution does not involve a huge web.config. Likewise, I'd much prefer to avoid writing custom code for the purpose of authentication.

Comment: Is it just me, or have you forgotten to state the actual question(s) ?

Answer (score 1):

In the following links you have a series of OData authentication options. If you don't know exactly what you want then that is a really good place to start and see what options you have.

> [Part1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/05/10/odata-and-authentication-part-1.aspx)
>
> [Part2...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/05/10/odata-and-authentication-part-1.aspx)